# Build Steps for Makefile Project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use Eclipse to build some existing software (written in C), which is built with a Makefile. For this reason I created a 'Makefile project' in Eclipse.

However, I just found out, the in the 'C/C++ Build / Settings' menu, I only see the 'Binary Parsers' and 'Error Parsers' tabs. However, I really need the 'Build Steps' tabs, because I also need to add a post-build command.

How can I make the 'Build Steps' tab appear in my project?

Answer (score 2):

You should include those steps in the makefile. The reason pre-build and post-build steps are included in the default Eclipse C++ projects is that in that case Eclipse generates the makefile automatically, so if you want to do anything apart from building your code, you need to do it separately. But if you create the Makefile yourself, then you can include pre- and post-build steps in it.

Comment: Of course I understand that I can add these steps in the Makefile. However, in this case, the Makefile is used by many people in our company, while the post-build step that I want to execute (copy some files to a specific location) is specific for me. So it would be nice if I could use the 'build steps' from Eclipse for this. Also, I see absolutely no reason why these steps should not be available for a Makefile project.

Comment: Then try this: create a global makefile, which everyone uses, and create your own makefile, which calls the global makefile, plus includes steps that are only needed by you.

Comment: Can I name the custom file other than Makefile, say Makefile.local? How do I specify in Eclipse that it should use another file?

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same issue recently. There is how I've resolved it:

Wrote a script build.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

source env.sh
# do other steps
make debug
```

Then

```
chmod a+x build.sh
```

Configure the project:

Properties->C/C++ Build->Behavior->Build (incremental build): empty

Properties->C/C++ Build->Builder Settings->Build command: ${ProjDirPath}/build.sh