# Can I run a post-build step after a makefile build in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to get a post-build step to run after building a makefile target from Eclipse. Since it's a makefile project, there are no Post-Build options.

I am aware of similar questions to this (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651908/build-steps-for-makefile-project-in-eclipse)), but unfortunately none of the answers work for me as the answer is essentially "put your build steps in the makefile". But my post-build step processes the build log that Eclipse generates, which of course doesn't exist until `make` completes.

Is there no way at all of running a post-build step after the `make` process has run? I'd accept that the answer is simply "no", but I'd appreciate if anyone can confirm that.

Comment: Does changing the "Build command" from `make` to `make && my_post_build_script` work?

Comment: No, it just passes "&&" to make as a target: `make: *** No rule to make target '&&'.  Stop.`

Comment: What is in the build log that Eclipse generates?

Comment: It's just the output from make, saved to a text file.

Comment: I could do a load of piping, redirection etc. in the makefile itself but I was hoping to avoid that if possible (for a whole bunch of reasons related to the build process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to get Eclipse to perform an explicit post-build step in a makefile project, but it seems fairly straightforward to work around it. Here is one suggestion:

Write a second makefile called `makefile-wrapper` that looks like this:

```
all:
    make > build.log
    post-build-script.sh build.log
```

Then set the build command in Eclipse to `make -f makefile-wrapper`.

When Eclipse invokes `make -f makefile-wrapper`, it will run the recipe given above, which will invoke `make` again, saving its output to `build-log.txt`. The recursive invocation will use your real makefile (due to the absence of an `-f` argument in the recursive invocation), and save its output, which is then available for your post-build script to process.

Comment: This seems like the easiest answer to the problem - for various reasons it doesn't quite help in my specific case, but marked as the solution as it's generally sound.